# Find the length of the sides of an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $6$cm.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> An equilateral triangle ABC is inscribed in a circle of radius $6$ cm. O is the centre of the circle. Find its sides.

What I did:-
I joined OB and OA and by applying trigonometry in triangle OAB, tried finding sides of equilateral triangle. But realized it wasn't a right angled triangle. How to find the sides?

Comment: I thought https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2379298/306553 solves the problem, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry @SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 1):

Drop a perpendicular from the center of the circle to one of the sides and draw the radius to one of its endpoints. This should give you some nice triangles to play with :)